# Spring Boot 3 + Kotlin = "Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8."

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to compile / run a fresh created "hello world" type Spring Boot application in VS Code.

- Spring boot is Version 3.0.5
- Java is pinned to 17 in pom.xml
- Kotlin Compiler is 1.7.22 in pom.xml
- I have "kotlin.compiler.jvm.target": "17" in the project settings.json

When I compile, I get the error `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option kotlin(INLINE_FROM_HIGHER_PLATFORM)` in the "**KotlinSampleApplication.kt**" / "**runApplication**".

When I remove "**kotlin.compiler.jvm.target**" from the settings.json, it complains about running JVM 1.8 target code in an bytecode builds for Java 17 (== the other way around)

It looks like some of the Spring Boot dependencies are build with Java 17 and some with Java 1.8.
How can I get the application to run?

Comment: For me adding `"kotlin.compiler.jvm.target": "17"` in the project settings.json resolved the compiler error in SpringBoot main class

Comment: I have the same issue. 
I couldn't find settings.json, but I tried to go into
IntelliJ > Settings > Kotlin Compiler > Target JVM version > 17

Unfortunately the warning is still there

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Intelij IDEA, overrided the config of `build.gradle.kt`, so in Settings (Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Kotlin Compiler) I replaced "Target JVM version" option from 1.8 to 17, and works fine.

My `build.gradle.kt`:

```
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
    ...
    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    ...
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "17"
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it (in IntelliJ IDEA) by going to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing` and changing the `JDK for Importer` setting to `17`.

Then, I made sure in the Module Settings that all SDKs were referencing the same JVM (in this case 17).

And the last step was to reload the maven project.

In my `pom.xml`, I have this configuration:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.8.22</kotlin.version>
</properties>
```

and:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
        </args>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can run gradle run normally , but I encountered this issue while running the Junit test .

> Then I found that the jvmTarget for the main module in my project is 17, but the jvmTarget for the test module is 1.8 .
> at :
> "Project Structure --> Modules --> main or test --> Target paltform to JVM17 .
>
> [Project Structure --> Modules --> main or test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXFii.png)

Then I modified this configuration :

```kotlin
//val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
//compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
```

Change to :

```kotlin
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().all {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the
***Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8 error***
in a Spring Boot 3 and Kotlin project,

---

> you should update your IntelliJ IDEA to version 2023.03 or later

---

This newer version of IntelliJ provides better support for JVM 17, ensuring compatibility with projects that use newer JVM targets while working with Kotlin and Spring Boot 3. This update should effectively address the bytecode inlining issue related to different JVM targets.

[image: image of help]

Comment: The OP is using VS Code, not IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Initially, the context was a bit unclear as my search engine directed me to this question while I was looking for solutions in IntelliJ. However, I now understand that the Original Poster (OP) is using VS Code. While I recommend giving IntelliJ a try for the current situation, it could be worthwhile to revisit the issue once VS Code is updated to resolve it. Cheers!